# C++ inheritance and return values of method

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

In the code below `foo` returns a type A object by value. Can I somehow convert this without handy interaction into a object of type B? (Note: class A includes all data/storage mebers, class B just introduces more methods)

```
class A{
   /*data*/
   A foo(...);
};

class B: public A
{
/*no-data*/
  B doMagic(...);
};

/*usage*/
B bone;
B btwo = bone.foo(...) /*w\o cast*/
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm honestly trying, but I can't understand what you want based on how you worded this. Can you add some more information and reword it?

Comment: `class B, public A` should be `class B : public A`. Also, do you need to return the object by value or could you live with returning (smart-)pointers?

Comment: I have not well understood your question but it sounds like you need some sort of polymorphism may be?

Comment: Whats your problem? Apart from the typo `class B, public A` all looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, and that doesn't make sense the way you wrote it; and you also got syntax errors.

You cannot convert actual base *objects* to derived objects, and you can't usually sensibly go the other way, either. The usual thing you *can* do is convert pointers and references.

In your case, you would typically use a covariant return value on a virtual function:

```
struct A
{
  virtual A * foo();
};

struct B : A
{
  virtual B * foo();  // OK, this _overrides_ A::foo()
};

int main()
{
  B x;
  B * p = x.foo(); // no cast
}
```

You will need to think carefully about many, many details when pursuing this approach. It's certainly feasible, but you have to get a lot of things right. You will probably need a couple of custom constructors to make `B::foo()` do anything sensible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. `A::foo` returns an `A`, thats how its defined, so thats what it does. Even though `B` contains no extra data, I don't think C++ can know that.

A couple of alternatives you you could try instead:

Have a `B` contstractor which creates from an A parameter. Although I guess this effectively a cast.

```
class B, public A
{
    /*no-data*/
    B( const A& param );
    B doMagic(...);
};

/*usage*/
B bone;
B btwo = bone.foo(...);
```

Or another strategy, make the `doMagic` a static method which works on an `A` parameter. I am assuming the whole point of this is you want to run the doMagic method on the result of `A::foo`

```
class B, public A
{
    /*no-data*/
    static B doMagic(A& param, ...);
};

/*usage*/
B bone;
A atwo = bone.foo(...);
B::doMagic( atwo, ... );
```

Don't know if these will work for you, but hopefully they help.

Comment: That's C style, I already havetendencies to do so, but it screws the whole C++ concept... (not to say coding guidlines)